# Comparing values in the data selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I would like to get all elements with a certain `data-` value. This value changes at runtime, so using the standard attribute selector:

```
[data-mydatakey='value']
```

will not work.

My current selector is as follows:

```
$("input:data(isapproved)").each(...
```

This seems to select only elements which have had the respective data value set.

What I would like, is ideally something like this:

```
$("input:data(isapproved='true')").each(...

$("input:data(category='abcd')").each(...
```

Comment: did they really add a selector like this in newer versions `:data(isapproved='true')` ..?

Comment: Why the downvote? `:data(...)` is perfectly valid: http://api.jqueryui.com/data-selector/

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy it is from jQuery UI

Comment: why don't you use a custom [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) like `$("input").filter(function () {
    return $(this).data('category') == 'abcd'
}).each()`

Comment: @ArunPJohny If you add that as an answer, I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) like

```
$("input").filter(function () {
    return $(this).data('category') == 'abcd'
}).each()
```